# Two way binding with an enum in a select tag using AngularJS and TypeScript

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, enums

So I've got an object coming in from my database filled with a handful of variables and one variable of type genericEnum, and genericEnum is defined as such.

```
export enum GenericEnum {
     optionOne = 1,
     optionTwo = 2,
     optionThree = 3,
     optionFour = 4,
     optionFive = 5,
     optionSix = 6
}
```

So right now this object comes down, and the variable let's just call it selectOptions, comes down from the database and is equal to 4. So

```
selectOptions: GenericEnum = 4;
```

I'm trying to two way bind the variable to a select tag such that, if an option is picked say, "optionSix" then the variable's value is changed from 4 to 6.

Here's the HTML I have so far trying to make this work out.

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.myObject.selectOptions">
                <option value="1">Option One</option>
                <option value="2">Option Two</option>
                <option value="3">Option Three</option>
                <option value="4">Option Four</option>
                <option value="5">Option Five</option>
                <option value="6">Option Six</option>
            </select>
```

So ideally on page load the drop down box shows a pre-selected option equal the current value of the variable on load time. So the dropdown box would say, "Option Four." Then if I were to select, "Option Six", save that choice and reload the page, the variable selectOptions would = 6, so the drop down box would be pre-selected as saying, "Option Six"

Right now when I load the page the drop down box is loading in as blank instead of loading in as, "Option Four." When I expand my box all the options are available to pick from, but the variable selectOptions equals 4, so I expected the dropdown box to have selected this option by default, but it seems to not be the case. I think it has something to do with how TypeScript converts an enum.

For example this is the resulting javascript for my enum

[Typescript Playground Enum Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20enum%20GenericEnum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionOne%20%3D%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionTwo%20%3D%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionThree%20%3D%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionFour%20%3D%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionFive%20%3D%205%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionSix%20%3D%206%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

In a separate stack overflow I was reading something about utilizing ng-repeat's (key, value) ability but was failing to get it to function as well, and wondering if that is perhaps not the route for me.

If I didn't explain the expected behaviour of the select element well enough please let me know so I can try to provide more information, thanks for any and all help everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tl;dr at the bottom if you want the general gist of the solution.

So I ended up finding a solution to this issue and wanted to share it with everyone in case someone else might find it helpful in the future.

In my Angular controller for this page I had to reconstruct my enum as an array Like so

```
selectOptionTypes: any[] = [];

$onInit(): void {
    this.buildSelectOptionTypesList();
}

buildSelectOptionTypesList = () => {
    this.selectOptionTypes.push({ value: 1, key: 'Option One' });
    this.selectOptionTypes.push({ value: 2, key: 'Option Two' });
    this.selectOptionTypes.push({ value: 3, key: 'Option Three' });
    this.selectOptionTypes.push({ value: 4, key: 'Option Four' });
    this.selectOptionTypes.push({ value: 5, key: 'Option Five' });
    this.selectOptionTypes.push({ value: 6, key: 'Option Six' });
}
```

Then in the html I created a select statement using ng-options and ng-model like so.

```
<select 
    ng-model="$ctrl.myObject.selectOptions" 
    ng-options="option.value as option.key for option in $ctrl.selectOptionTypes"
>
</select>
```

This generated my drop down box of 6 items and on load would pre-select whichever option corresponded to the numeric value of my model variable, "myObject.selectOptions"

myObject.selectOptions came down from the database with a value of 4 so the 4th option of my drop down box was automatically selected and displayed. Also upon changing the value the both manually in the database, or through the picking a different option in the drop down box the variable's value would change, and on load the drop down box would reflect that new change.

So this is the solution I've found to dynamically set an option in a HTML Select tag to selected="selected" based on a the current value of a two way bound variable via ng-model.

**In summary:** if your variable is of type enum, reconstruct that enum as an array in your controller. Set your ng-model to equal your variable, and set ng-options in relation to the array version of your enum utilizing ng-options' built in key and value abilities.

More information on ng-options can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) in Angular's Directives Documentation